# Proving that there are models of ZF- where the axiom of regularity fails

Tags: set-theory

I began learning set independently recently. I wanted to show that the axiom of regularity (alternatively called the axiom of foundation) was independent of the other axioms of ZF at least in so far as models where it fails exist.

My idea was to append a "set" defined by $x = \{x\}$ to a 'standard' model. I have realised that I don't really know how one would proceed in showing that this works. A quick google search didn't yield much (at least to my eyes).

Are there basic techniques for constructing models of set theories, or do they require more advanced tools? I have some ideas but I want to avoid jumping down a rabbit hole.

Comment: I think you mean models of ZF-.

Comment: @J.G. Can you elaborate? I am new to the subject

Comment: By definition, regularity is a ZF axiom, so is true in all its models. The axioms besides regularity are called ZF-.

Comment: @J.G. You can do this via class models and prove the axioms as a schema, thus avoiding the problem.

Comment: @J.G.: Is the "-" at the end supposed to be a minus sign? Then it would be a good idea to use MathJax to obtain $\rm ZF-$, as the hyphen is close to invisible.

Comment: [This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#Regularity_and_the_rest_of_ZF(C)_axioms) doesn't give all the details, but recommends some reading that will.

Comment: With perhaps too many details, but the late Matti Rubin used to teach this in his set theory class, the notes are still available as of Nov. 2019: https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~matti/Axiomatic-ST-2012-09--Negation-of-Fnd-is-consistent.pdf

Comment: You may refer Aczel's "Non-well-founded sets". He constructed a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}^-+\mathsf{AFA}$ by using the means of *system*. (where $\mathsf{ZFC}^-$ is $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without regularity.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real way to give an absolute construction a model of ZF minus regularity in ZFC (and a fortiori ZF), since it is equiconsistent with ZFC: any such model's class of well founded sets form a model of ZF and that model's class of constructible sets forms a model of ZFC, so we'd be in violation of the incompleteness theorem. Instead, we can do a relative construction from a model of ZFC that already exists. One approach is to construct a model inside a pre-existing model of your base theory. This is basically equivalent to constructing (in your base theory) a class such that we can prove the relativization to that class of any axiom of the theory of interest (called a "proper class model" when we aren't being pedantic). This is the approach taken in the examples above of the well-founded sets and the constructible sets. The other main approach is using forcing to extend pre-existing models, and that certainly qualifies as a more advanced tool, but we don't need it here.

ZF without regularity has a strong relationship to another theory, ZFA$^1$, which is set theory with atoms. Basically, in addition to the sets, we have a class of atoms that can be elements of sets but have no elements themselves. Note that foundation is still an axiom of ZFA: intuitively instead of every set being "built up" from the empty set as in the cumulative hierarchy, we also allow the atoms as building blocks. What really is being modified is extensionality, since the atoms have no elements, but are distinct from the empty set.

To see the relationship, imagine a model of ZFA with exactly one atom. Nothing is stopping us from saying that instead of having no elements, that atom has only itself as an element (hence is a Quine atom). Then we get can get extensionality back by identifying sets with the same elements, e.g. if $a$ is the atom, $a$, $\{a\}$, and $\{\{a\}\}$ and so on, were previously distinct sets, but no longer. But of course we lost foundation, so we have a model of ZF with regularity replaced by its negation. More complicated examples can be constructed (e.g. "double Quine atoms" with $a=\{b\}$ and $b=\{a\}$).

This is pretty close in spirit from your initial impression that we should just append a Quine atom somehow. But we started from a model of ZFA, whereas we wanted to start from a model of ZF. But it's no worry: we can build models of ZFA inside models of ZF. (And the converse, which is slightly easier: just take the subclass of "pure" sets without atoms in their transitive closure.) Just grab two different infinite subsets of $\omega$, call one the empty set and the other the atom, let $X=\{r_1,r_2\}$ and then recursively construct the hierarchy $C_0=X,$ $$C_{\alpha+1}=P(C_\alpha)-\emptyset,$$ $C_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}C_\lambda.$ Then $C=\bigcup_\alpha C_\alpha$ is a model of ZFA with one atom. This can be generalized to produce models with any set-sized collection of atoms... the only important thing is you start with your empty set and atoms having the same rank so they don't wind up accidentally having elements. (See also the [approach](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~matti/axiomatic-set-theory-2003-4-1.course/urelements-2010.pdf) in another one from the same series of Matti Rubin's notes that Asaf linked in the comments. You can tag the atoms with a 0 and the sets with a 1. He shows you can also get a proper class of atoms this same way.)

There is also a very simple approach that does not go through ZFA that I can't remember where I learned. Start with a model $(V,\in)$ of ZF. Define the relation $E$ on $V$ as follows: Let $E$ be the same as $\in$, except make $1$ $E$-empty and $0$ have $0$ as its only $E$-element. It’s straightforward but tedious to check that all of ZF except foundation holds in $(V,E).$

More generally, for any permutation $\sigma$ of $V$ you can define $E$ by $a E b\iff a\in \sigma(b).$ The above is the special case where the permutation swaps $0$ and $1$. This allows you to make models with more general violations than just having a Quine atom.

Another approach is anti-foundation axioms, which are more principled choices of axioms that conflict with regularity rather than just 'there are Quine atoms'. You can read all about them in Aczel's [book](http://www.irafs.org/courses/materials/aczel_set_theory.pdf). The approach to consistency is similar (he constructs a "proper class model"), but more complicated due to the more demanding nature of the antifoundation axiom than just the negation of regularity.

$^1$ As an aside, ZFA is important in the study of the axiom of choice, since it is the theory in which [permutation models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_model) are built, which were historically the first models constructed that exhibited the failure of the axiom of choice and can often be reworked into symmetric models of the failure of choice in ZF.

Comment: Matti's note that you link from 2010 were written when I took that course. (The notes I linked in the comments are from the time he taught the course after that, from 2012, so not exactly the same series...)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this